# Elasticsearch 7.7 how to read several documents, not fetch all the documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 7.7 in CentOS 8 box. I could creat index, type by REST format by command curl. For example, I could use

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/testindex2"

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex2/man/1/" -d '{ "name" : "shiny2", "age": 28}'

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex2/man/1/" 

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex2/man/_search?pretty"
```

But if I have inserted many documents, how could I do query by `REST` command line using command `curl` to find particular `age = 28's` documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex2/_search?pretty&q=age:28"
```

that is the simplest way to query.

more option and documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/search-search.html

also you can use Match or Term query with JSON body format.

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testindex2/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "age": {
        "value": "28"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

more documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: How to do query age:28 and name:shiny2? I did not find the right grammar.